# Stata Import File - Troubleshooting

Tags: stata

I am having difficulty importing a [CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DW7ve.png) into Stata. I have tried using the import delimited feature. Stata does not recognize the semi-colon separated data as separate data points. I also have access to a [plain text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGMaN.png) but I haven't had success with that either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Solved this myself by converting all semicolons to commas in txt file.

Comment: Good that you solved this, but in a programming forum you should show exact code used, not just discuss it.

Answer (score 3):

I see that you've figured out a solution already, but did you specify "delimiters(";")" when you were using "import delimited"? Otherwise, Stata assumes the delimiters are commas.

Comment: I did. Yes. Thank you.

Comment: 'import delimited' in Stata 17 and above has improved delimiter detection and will detect semicolon delimiters automatically. Prior to Stata 17, you will need to use the "delimiters(";")" option.